# Mongoose, не работает с репликой

Tags: docker, mongodb, docker-compose, mongoose

Монго работает в докере. Пытаюсь подключится так:

```
const mongoURI = `mongodb://192.168.0.111:27020/admin?replicaSet=rs0`;
```

Получаю:

```
MongoDB connection error: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Из него (контейнера) - все ок.

```
root@mongodb:/# mongo 127.0.0.1/admin?replicaSet=rs0
```

Прикладываю конфиг к докеру: https://pastebin.com/UfeAT4CE

Если подключить в mongoose так, тоже работает:

const mongoURI = `mongodb://192.168.0.111:27020/admin`;

Только вот когда использую транзакции,  ошибка: "Cannot run command against the "admin" database in a transaction."

Вот, что пишут в документации: https://prnt.sc/v8sgqa

Comment: Ну по ощущениям что причиной есть настройка реплики. 
Покажите `rs.conf()`  , может там binding к localhost , а это мне думается с точки зрения mongo не то же самое что 127.0.0.1

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#replicaset-hostnames

Но с другой стороны внутри контейнера к 127.0.0.1 есть подключение...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hT6R7z79

Comment: Таки попробуйте сконфигурировать чтоб localhost:27017 стал 127.0.0.1

Comment: А разве это не одно и тоже? https://pastebin.com/Jnb00ZL2

Comment: я сталкивался неоднократно при бинде ip в настройках приложений localhost  и  127.0.0.1 это не одно и то же.

Comment: Ну т.е. смотрите, представьте что у вас есть два домена. one.com  и two.com  которые ведут на один и тот же ip.  Можете ли вы утверждать что one.com одно и то же что и two.com ? С точки зрения ip да, но приложение если привязано к hostname очевидно что для него это разные вещи. Так же как и 127.0.0.1 и locahost, т.к. localhost это попросту hostname ведущий на 127.0.0.1

Comment: Ну и последнее. Мне думается что с точки зрения контейнера после проброса destination адрес контейнер будет видеть свой внешний ip, а не localhost. Так же вероятно вам нужно будет биндить либо на все адреса что не очень безопасно, либо хотя бы на  подсеть контейнера.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/

Comment: Касательно доменов (one, two). По идеи это разные уровни модели OSI.